# Configure outlook calendar settings by scripting

Tags: powershell, microsoft-outlook-2016

We distribute an organizational form for our calendar.
How can we use scripting to load the form for every user?

right now users need to still open their calendar properties, open the select window for the form, add the form.

*i'm not talking about exchange, but outlook client 365*

Answer (score 1):

This is a VBA code snipped that sets the form for the particular [calendar] folder:

```
Set pa = CalendarFolder.PropertyAccessor
pa.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36DE0003", "IPM.Appointment.FormClass"
pa.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E6001F", "Form Display Name"
```

Feel free to use the same technique in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you. I have not cracked the solution yet, but you helped me on my way. I also found this article that explains what I want to do: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/globally-change-a-default-form